# what is the difference between f.call and f()

Tags: javascript

I used to use the anonymous self-execute function in js:

```
((function(){
  //do something
})();
```

However I found this somewhere:

```
((function(){
  //do something
}).call(this);
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example, `this` will be the global object (`window` in browser-land), unless you're in ES5 mode, in which it'll be `undefined`.

In the second example, `this` depends on what `this` was in the calling context- *either* `global` (`undefined` in ES5), ***or*** a object instance.

```
function Foo() {
    var that = this;

    (function () {
       console.log(this === window);
       console.log(this === that);
       console.log(typeof this === "undefined"); 
    }());

    (function () {
       console.log(this === window);
       console.log(this === that);
       console.log(typeof this === "undefined"); 
    }).call(this);

    (function () {
       "use strict";

       console.log(this === window);
       console.log(this === that); 
       console.log(typeof this === "undefined"); 
    }());
}

new Foo();​
```

[[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UbsLz/1/)]

You'll also find the `.call()` call is microscopically slower due to the extra work the engine has to do to set the `this` context up.

Comment: In ES5 strict mode, in the first example, `this` will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

if you pass `this`, both forms are equivalent.

But to see difference, check the program below

```
var x = 5;
var o = { x: 10 };

function f()
{
    alert(this.x);
}

f();
f.call(o);
```

> f() -> will alert 5.
>
> f.call(o) -> will alert 10.

Answer (score 0):

One calls it in the context of the default object (`window` in a browser), and the other calls it in the context of whatever `this` is. Unless you are inside some other function, or a `with` block, `this` will be the default object, so there isn't a difference in that particular example.

The context determines what value is assigned to `this` inside the function.